# How to Countifs with one column only counting unique values, and another counting all values except a specific one?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with filling out a table. Here's a link to an image of the table and my sample dataset: https://ibb.co/hsyycCC

1. I have to count all items that are either Size L or S..
2. ..thats assigned to their owner (John, Mark, Gina)..
3. ..thats either Colored (Y/N)..
4. ..that isn't tagged as "Keep"..
5. But I only have to count all the items with unique IDs (no duplicates)

I can do steps 1-4 with a Countifs function:
`=countifs(B:B,"<>Keep",C:C,"Yes",D:D,"L",E:E,"John")`
in cell H3 for example.

But I don't know how to integrate step number 5 to the formula! Can anyone help enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: So equal to ie "=" and not equal to ie "<>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed to add a helper column you could put in cell F2 and drag it down

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2,$A$1:A1,0),"U")
```

This would flag all the unique values with a U
in the helper column . Then in your COUNTIFS function, add the condition

```
F:F,"U".
```

There might be a fancier way to do it, but that will get the job done